# NSNumberFormatter right justification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumberformatter

i am using the following code for left justifying the numbers

```
  NSString *docStr=[contentDic objectForKey:@"Doc#"];
  NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]
  NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:docStr];
 [f release];
```

but i am not getting how to right justify the numbers,can some body explain me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The presentation of the number is not the same as the format of the number.

I'm assuming (because you haven't given any other details) that you are trying to display a number in a text field. In this case, since you already have a string, all you need to do is the set the display options in the text field to be right justified and just set its text value to your string - there is no need for the formatter.